# Receiving FK violation error when trying to save task in OfBiz

Tags: java, sql, apache, ofbiz

Having an issue creating a task in OfBiz 16.11.01. Standard build, doing some basic testing and when I try to create a task in a project, I'm receiving the following error related to a FK constraint violation:

(Error while inserting: [GenericEntity:WorkEffort][createdByUserLogin,admin(java.lang.String)][createdDate,2017-02-10 12:12:23.823(java.sql.Timestamp)][createdStamp,2017-02-10 12:12:23.823(java.sql.Timestamp)][createdTxStamp,2017-02-10 12:12:23.075(java.sql.Timestamp)][currentStatusId,PTS_CREATED(java.lang.String)][description,Initial meeting with stakeholders to define scope, etc.(java.lang.String)][estimatedCompletionDate,2017-02-10 00:00:00.0(java.sql.Timestamp)][estimatedStartDate,2017-02-10 00:00:00.0(java.sql.Timestamp)][lastModifiedByUserLogin,admin(java.lang.String)][lastModifiedDate,2017-02-10 12:12:23.823(java.sql.Timestamp)][lastStatusUpdate,2017-02-10 12:12:23.823(java.sql.Timestamp)][lastUpdatedStamp,2017-02-10 12:12:23.823(java.sql.Timestamp)][lastUpdatedTxStamp,2017-02-10 12:12:23.075(java.sql.Timestamp)][priority,1(java.lang.Long)][revisionNumber,1(java.lang.Long)][scopeEnumId,WES_PRIVATE(java.lang.String)][sequenceNum,1(java.lang.Long)][workEffortId,10076(java.lang.String)][workEffortName,Meet(java.lang.String)][workEffortParentId,10060(java.lang.String)][workEffortTypeId,Task(java.lang.String)]

(SQL Exception while executing the following:

INSERT INTO OFBIZ.WORK_EFFORT (WORK_EFFORT_ID, WORK_EFFORT_TYPE_ID, CURRENT_STATUS_ID, LAST_STATUS_UPDATE, WORK_EFFORT_PURPOSE_TYPE_ID, WORK_EFFORT_PARENT_ID, SCOPE_ENUM_ID, PRIORITY, PERCENT_COMPLETE, WORK_EFFORT_NAME, SHOW_AS_ENUM_ID, SEND_NOTIFICATION_EMAIL, DESCRIPTION, LOCATION_DESC, ESTIMATED_START_DATE, ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_DATE, ACTUAL_START_DATE, ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE, ESTIMATED_MILLI_SECONDS, ESTIMATED_SETUP_MILLIS, ESTIMATE_CALC_METHOD, ACTUAL_MILLI_SECONDS, ACTUAL_SETUP_MILLIS, TOTAL_MILLI_SECONDS_ALLOWED, TOTAL_MONEY_ALLOWED, MONEY_UOM_ID, SPECIAL_TERMS, TIME_TRANSPARENCY, UNIVERSAL_ID, SOURCE_REFERENCE_ID, FIXED_ASSET_ID, FACILITY_ID, INFO_URL, RECURRENCE_INFO_ID, TEMP_EXPR_ID, RUNTIME_DATA_ID, NOTE_ID, SERVICE_LOADER_NAME, QUANTITY_TO_PRODUCE, QUANTITY_PRODUCED, QUANTITY_REJECTED, RESERV_PERSONS, RESERV2ND_P_P_PERC, RESERV_NTH_P_P_PERC, ACCOMMODATION_MAP_ID, ACCOMMODATION_SPOT_ID, REVISION_NUMBER, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY_USER_LOGIN, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_BY_USER_LOGIN, LAST_UPDATED_STAMP, LAST_UPDATED_TX_STAMP, CREATED_STAMP, CREATED_TX_STAMP, SEQUENCE_NUM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

(INSERT on table 'WORK_EFFORT' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'WK_EFFRT_TYPE' for key (Task).  The statement has been rolled back.)))]

[image: Screenshot]

The statement appears to be submitting 'Task' as the workEffortTypeId which is listed in the WorkEffortType table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

may be WORK_EFFORT_TYPE_ID is null. you can load demo data for testing purpose